# Add date into a text area near an existing text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a text area with date input beneath it:

```
<textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="18 - 3rd Molar"><?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?>
</textarea>
<input type="date" id="onee" class="form-control"/>
```

And I need to use `jQuery` to detect a change of date value, and add it to the current text area, near the existing info inside of my text area:

[image]

As you see in the picture, if I chose a date, I need to add inside text area and add date near the text saying `crown, change #2 - day/month/year`.

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#onee").on('change', function()
  {
    var val = $("#onee").val();
    //Here can't know how to continue
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#onee").on('change', function()
  {
    var val = $("#onee").val();
    $('#one').val($('#one').val() + " " + val);
  });
```

Comment: I have 32 text area with 32 date for each, how can I apply it to of my elements

Comment: same functionality for 32 textarea?